# Retina Macbook Pro battery life

Tags: battery-life, macbook-pro-retina

What are normal figures for battery life on the newest Retina Macbook Pro systems and what could be draining battery. I have tried all of the tips on Apple support discussions and don't know if I should be getting better battery life.

Comment: Suppose we should also ask: what battery life are you actually getting?

Answer (score 1):

The battery life of any system depends what you do with it, both in terms of hourly usage and lifetime. The lifetime of the battery can be roughly determined by saying it has so many recharges before it dies.

The more you do on the system the quicker the batter drains. This can include running system heavy processes and using plugin media like printers, speakers and USB devices.

Methods of increasing your battery life can include not using peripherals where possible. There is also an argument for draining and recharging you battery and not leaving it plugged in when fully charged. I personally follow this since it's not hard to do, but another side suggests holding the battery at 80% or so.

Your specific system does seem to have battery trouble as suggested [here](http://www.imore.com/how-resolve-battery-life-troubles-your-retina-macbook-pro). The system you specified has a battery life up to 9 hours according to [Apple](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/features-retina/)

It is tempting to suggest reading material on good practice, but there are so many with varying results. Following the suggested methods are as good a start as any.

*Update*: Suggestion from [@Halest](https://superuser.com/users/310073/halest) would be to use an application called [coconutbattery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) to  "helps to find out if the battery health is bad in general because of usage".

Comment: I edited your post to change "perishables" to "peripherals", assuming it was a typo on your part. However, your next edit undid that change. Not sure if that was intentional or accidental, so not going to re-edit, just letting you know.

Comment: @Indrek | It was indeed a typo. Corrected it now. Thanks. Assume we edited at the same time.

Comment: There are tools like "Coconut Battery", which will tell you the health status and age of your battery. This should help you

Comment: @Halest | The OP has asked for methods of finding battery drain. Does this tool perform such a task?

Comment: @Matthew Not to my knowledge but it helps to find out if the battery health is bad in general because of usage and so on since there may not be a battery drain at all